# Can I power an ESP Dev Kit board through its PH2.0 battery adapter

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, battery-charging, esp32

I have a [WaveShare ESP32-S3-Touch-LCD-4.3](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/ESP32-S3-Touch-LCD-4.3). I want to create a case for it. For simplicity I would power it through the USB-C connector, but that'll increase the size for my case. On the underside of the board is a PH2.0 connector to connect batteries to. I'd prefer to use that connection to power the board. My question is whether I can.

The only documentation I could find on the battery connector is this from the linked page:

> PH2.0 battery header: The development board utilizes the efficient charge and discharge management chip CS8501. It can boost a single-cell lithium battery to 5V. Currently, the charging current is set at 580mA, and users can modify the charging current by replacing the R45 resistor. For more details, you can refer to Schematic diagram.

[image]

The schematic diagram is here:

https://files.waveshare.com/wiki/ESP32-S3-Touch-LCD-4.3/ESP32-S3-Touch-LCD-4.3-Sch.pdf

The battery section shows the power goes into a CS8501. I can't find any information on that. I have verified however that the connection has support for charging batteries. The chip must be there to implement this feature.

[image]

If I can drive power through it, are there any special considerations I need to make since this connection also supports charging batteries? I can look into disabling this from software, if that's possible. I do want to be able to connect the UART USB (the top one, not the highlighted one) to update the software without disconnecting the power supply. If this is not possible, the I can manage of course.

Comment: I have read the datasheet and cannot find a reason why this should not work.